# System.OutOfMemoryException on multiple asynchronous calls to a WCF service

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, asynchronous

I have a windows service that is executing multiple asynchronous calls to a WCF service simultaneously (using a Parallel.Foreach loop).

The WCF service is generating multiple System.OutOfMemory exceptions.

Is there something I need to configure for multithreading to run successfully? I was of the understanding that IIS managed the threading resources.. I believe my understanding is incorrect.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: What work is being undertaken each time the service is called?

Comment: do less calls. how ever i dont think there is any other thing you can do. what if out of memory is caused just by one call?

Comment: does one single call complete? What does your WCF do? Any Code?

Comment: Also show the server code.

Comment: Do you use DataTables in the calls. There was a oom problem a longer time, ago.

Comment: To answer your questions: single calls complete successfully. The WCF code executed is complex.. Numerous validations of an excel file hence why I didn't post it. Sound like you're advocating limiting the number of simultaneous calls.

Comment: There is a defect in your code that causes excessive memory usage. Many parallel calls send resource usage over the edge. The question cannot be answered without seeing the defective code. Closing this for now.

Comment: Excel files you say.....do you just mean csv or are you doing server-side Excel interop?

Comment: not using Excel interop but a different 3rd party tool that loads the excel file into memory

Comment: Think you really need to show us some code.  How big are the files? What is the 3rd party tool? Are you disposing resources correctly?  What instancing and concurrency mods are you using for WCF? 32bit/64bit? You also mention a windows service and IIS, are you using WAS?

Comment: To update everyone, I had a big glaring memory leak which after further investigation I discovered. Thank you for your help. Sorry I didn't post up the code.. in all honesty there was so much of it that trying to make it in anyways readable would have been a challenge.

Answer (score -2):

Add that to your web.config:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```